# Verification of Orthogonality Integral by Direct Integration

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, orthogonality, heat-equation

How do I verify the orthogonality integral by direct integration? I've been told that its necessary to use the equation that defines λ<sub>n</sub>:

κλ<sub>n</sub>cos(λ<sub>n</sub>a)+*h*sin(λ<sub>n</sub>a)=0

I understand that two non-zero functions, *f(x)* and *g(x)* are said to be orthogonal on [a,b] if,

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx = 0$$

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to verify that two functions are orthogonal. What are the two functions?

Comment: The two functions are sin(λn*x) and sin( λm*x), where n≠m and λn=(2n-1)π/2a